# What to return for Bluebird Promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, bluebird, es6-promise

happy new year!

I would be very thankful if anybody could give me a hint on an issue with  [Bluebird's promisify](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html). Without further ado, the situation is as follows. I have this piece of code:

```
/**
* Set up /website endpoint.
* @param {Object} router A Koa router
*/
module.exports = function(router) {
/**
* POST /website
*
* Records the activity of following an external
* website URL.
*/
  router.post('/website', validator, (ctx, next) => co(function * () {
    var address = forwardedFor(ctx.request, ctx.request.headers);
    var orgId = /\/?([^\-]+).*/.exec(ctx.request.body.path)[1];

    var visit = {
      websiteUrl: ctx.request.body.url,
      path: ctx.request.body.path,
      clientIp: address.ip,
      userAgent: ctx.request.headers['user-agent'],
      organization: orgId
    };
    yield tracker.track('website_visit', visit);
    log.info('Tracked [%s] website visit from client %s@%s%s', visit.websiteUrl, address.ip, orgId, visit.path);

    ctx.status = 200;
    ctx.body = {
      success: true,
      timestamp: Date.now(),
      data: visit
    };
    return next();
  })());
};
```

which at certain point calls:

```
/**
* Register the `event` with the given `name`.
* @method track
* @param  {String} name  The name or type of the event to be saved.
* @param  {Object} event Payload to register as an event.
* @return {Promise}       A promise on tracking the event.
*/
function track(name, event) {
  var entity = seneca.make(DEFAULT_BASE, name, event);
  var save$ = Promise.promisify(entity.save$, { context: entity });
  return save$();
}
```

This finally calls:

```
module.exports = function phonecall() {
  var seneca = this;

  seneca.add('cmd:save,role:entity,name:website_visit', function(msg, respond) {
    var visit = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(msg.ent.data$(false)));
    Organization.where('account_no', 'like', `%${visit.organization}%`)
      .fetch()
      .then(function(org) {
        return User
          .where('id_organization', org.get('id'))
          .fetch()
          .then(function(user) {
            delete visit.organization;
            var v = new WebsiteVisit(visit);
            user.websiteVisits().create(v);
            return user.save(null, {
              method: 'update'
            });
          });
      })
      .then((model) => {
        return {
          ok: true,
          model: model
        };
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        return {
          ok: false,
          why: err.message || err
        };
      }).asCallback(respond);
  });

  return {
    name: PLUGIN_NAME
  };
};
```

That is on a complete different application.

The main problem is that everything runs smoothly, and the model is inserted into the database. However, `yield tracker.track('website_visit', visit);` takes forever and doesn't behave asynchronously, which launches a timeout error for the already completed function.

The ideal behaviour for `yield tracker.track('website_visit', visit);` would be to operate on a different thread (asynchronously), as a normal promise should, but isn't acting as such...

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: Promises don't turn your synchronous code into asynchronous code, if that's what you think.

Comment: I'm aware that promises don't turn the code into an asynchronous one, but emulate said behaviour by making it possible for the code to keep running while waiting for the promise to be fulfilled.

Comment: If you think about it, that's the same thing as *"turn the code into an asynchronous one"*. Promises emulate nothing. They are an abstraction over asynchronicity, they do not create asynchronicity. That has to be there up-front, in the form of some code that explicitly runs on a different thread and invokes callbacks when it's done. If you have code that takes a while and runs on the same thread, then promise will not change that fact.

Comment: Ok. However the problem isn't the time it takes for the code to run, but rather that the promise is waiting for a response that for whatever reason isn't arriving, despite having included a `return` and `.asCallback(respond)` function.

On the other hand, as far as I know, promises work with/as callbacks, I'm not really sure about the relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The yield expression requires explicit instructions to continue execution. It's built to give you the ability to stop and start the execution of a process. In your case, this is doesn't seem to be needed. Unless I'm mistaken, it looks like all you need is to wait for the results of an asynchronous function before proceeding which is just standard use case for a Promise.

Why not just use the same Promise architecture you're using in the phoneCall function?

Comment: Well, the original code was done by another programmer, who I'm trying to get in touch with (I asked myself the same question). But I'll definitly give it a try. Thanks!